# Does this actually ensure that a number is between 1-9?

Tags: c++

```
int position = 0;

void set_position() {

  std::cout << "Player " << player << "'s Turn (Enter 1-9): ";

  while (!(std::cin >> position)) {

    std::cout << "Player " << player << ", please enter a valid number between 1 and 9: ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();

  }

  std::cout << "\n";

  while (board[position-1] != " ") {

    std::cout << "Oops, there's already something in that position!\n\n";

    std::cout << "Player " << player << "'s Turn (Enter 1-9): ";
    std::cin >> position;

    std::cout << "\n";
  }

}
```

This is a solution to a tic tac toe challenge in Codecademy and I would like to understand if the function `while (!std::cin >> position))` actually checks if it is 1 to 9.  Position is just an `int`, declared as `int position = 0;`. How does this actually check if it's 1 through 9? Or does it just check if it's an integer? So far Codecademy's C++ course seems to be pretty bad and doesn't go through that much.

Comment: When you tried to input an integer smaller than 1 or larger than 9, what happened?

Comment: No the shown code does not really check this.

Comment: `while (!(std::cin >> position) || position < 1 || position > 9)`

Comment: I downvoted because [there appears to have been no effort to debug the code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: @ArminMontigny Thanks for your feedback. Anyway, the link I posted has a section “What to do next” which contains useful information. A programming newbie should learn to debug as early as possible to prevent lots of wasted time. And I find posting a notice about a downvote useful for OP, so they can ping me back when they improve their post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Too Long Didn't Read (TLDR)

That code only filters out non-numbers.

#### Explanation:

To help you understand, lets look at what actually happens inside

```
while(!(std::cin >> position))
```

On the inside of all that lies `std::cin >> position`.  `>>` is the "extraction operator", so we're going to extract something from `std::cin` (standard input).  Using the `>>` operator really just turns around and calls `operator>>()` on the given object.  The given object in this case is a std::istream.  It's `operator>>()` call signature looks like:

```
istream& operator>> (int& val)
```

It returns an `istream` (itself), and takes a reference to an `int`, `position` in your case.

So if we evaluate `std::cin >> position` mentally (or in a debugger, which is much better: zero guesswork), we'll see that we've returned that `istream` (which is almost certainly a `return *this;` at the end of the function).

Now lets replace `std::cin >> position` with the effective return value `std::cin` and see what the code looks like.

```
while(!(std::cin))
```

Okay, so we need to apply the `!` operator to the `istream` named `cin`.  "Wait what?!" you cry... Any class/struct can define a variety of different operators, such as `<<, >>, =, ==, >, <, !, *, ->...`  there's a bunch of them.  The relevant one is the `!` operator, with the following function signature and documentation:

```
bool operator!() const
```

> Returns true if either failbit or badbit is set, and false otherwise. This is equivalent to calling member fail.

Incidentally, the `const` on the end means "we promise not to change the object running the function".  This allows the compiler to make various optimizations, knowing the object's state won't change.  It also lets our fellow programmers know what sorts of things are happening (and *not* happening) inside the function.

We'd expect that this would return true (fail or bad was set) when you type a non-digit into `operator>>(int&)`, and we'd be right.  Cheers to the library designers for following the "Principle of Least Surprise".

The return of value of `operator!()` is then passed into the while loop.  So if someone types a letter or punctuation or what have you, they'll see the error message and have to type again.

#### Conclusion:

This doesn't do anything for filtering out numbers outside of 1-9, it just filters out non-numbers.  You'd need new code for that, such as the suggestion in the comment by @Eljay.